# spring-xd custom redis-sink

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-data-redis

So I think I need to extend the current redis-sink provided in spring-xd to write into a redis Capped list, rather than creating a new one but unfortunately it seems it gets worse as I will have to go deeper into spring-integration and further back into spring-data (spring-data-redis) because the whole redis-sink seems to be based on the generic pub/sub abstraction on redis - or is there some type of handler that can be defined once the message arrives to the channel handler?

In order to have the "effect of a capped list" when I push data redis, I need to execute both a redis "push" and then an "rtrim" as outlined here - http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro. If I am to build a custom spring-integration / spring-data module. I believe I see support for the "ltrim" but not the"rtrim" operation here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.7.0.RC1/api/

Any Advice on how/where to start or an easier approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually even Redis doesn't have such a `RTRIM` [command](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim). We don't need it because we reach the same behavior with the negative indexes for `LTRIM`:

> start and end can also be negative numbers indicating offsets from the end of the list, where -1 is the last element of the list, -2 the penultimate element and so on.

I think you should use `<redis:store-outbound-channel-adapter>` and add something like this into its configuration:

```
<int-redis:request-handler-advice-chain>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
        <beans:property name="onSuccessExpression" value="#redisTemplate.boundListOps(${keyExpression}).trim(1, -1)"/>
    </beans:bean>
</int-redis:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

To remove the oldest element in the Redis List.

Comment: sorry you are right i got my Ls and Rs mixed up. let me try what you suggest. that was exactly the type of thing i was looking for to avoid rewriting a custom outbound-channel-adapter. i keep forgetting about how/when to use the SPEL expressions. I will follow the instructions here I guess to deploy it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples/tree/master/redis-store-sink

Comment: so when i look at the source for [RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/redis/outbound/RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter.java) I see that the default redis operation is "left push"

Comment: And? It is fully different story. That component is exactly for the queue-like behavior. Although we can do the same `ltrim` there as well, but I'd not mix concerns from the architecture perspective.

Comment: lpush collection 1
lpush collection 2
lpush collection 3
lpush collection 4
lpush collection 5 
lrange collection 0 -1
1) "5"
2) "4"
3) "3"
4) "2"
5) "1" 
I want to remove the oldest element, in this case the "1" or the fifth element, not the newest element . This seems difficult the way the ltrim command works. I can definitely remove the oldest element with a ```ltrim collection 0 -2``` but that does not allow me to build keep the collection a maximum arbitrary size.

Comment: So I think I really need to specify to the RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter to use a rpush command rather than lpush, then the ltrim command so the redisTemplate spel would look like #redisTemplate.boundListOps(${keyExpression}).trim(0, 5) to keep the newest 5 elements. 
Correct? If so, how to I change the default leftPush flag in the RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter and override the supplied redis:sink to use it?

Comment: See https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3932. We support `leftPush = false` since `SI-4.2.5`. So, you should just override/add new Redis module in the XD and utilize that feature for the `RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter` with an appropriate `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`.

Comment: Yes i knew it was in there, i could see it in the source linked above. the ExpressionEvaluationRequestHandlerAdvice appears to be based on lifecycle methods on the handling the request not about constructing the RedisQueueOutboundChannelAdapter itself so if you can point me to an example of that, I can take a look. I don't see much information about extending existing spring-xd modules so I am following the guide here as best I can http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/0.1.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/creating-a-sink-module.html.

Comment: That manual for the custom module is fine. Regarding `ExpressionEvaluationRequestHandlerAdvice` you can read SI Referennce Manual (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice) and take a look into samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more

Comment: From other side `ltrim` isn't a **remove** command. It is more like `retain`. That's why my sample "1, -1" demonstrate how to move the list outside of the oldest element.

Comment: I am being asked by StackOverFlow to not have extended discussions. Artem, if you would please look at my write-up [here](https://github.com/petergdoyle/estreaming/blob/master/spring-xd-samples-min/Notes_For_Artem.md), it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that! I think we will continue our discussion there in your project. E.g. via a new GH issue :-). Will update here, when we reach the good solution.